# UML in revision control systems

Tags: version-control, documentation, uml

I understand project documentation as being part of a software project evolution, sometimes tied together with code (especially in lean methodologies). That's why I think it might be a good idea to keep it together with code in the Revision Control system (such as git, in my case).

Markdown seems to be a widely adopted and working solution for collaboratively editing text documents. However, when it comes to entity-relationship or sequence diagrams I don't know which formats/software to use so that it's still possible to diff and merge.

So my questions are:

- Is it actually a good idea to keep code and documentation in the same repository?
- If yes, which format would you use for diagrams?

I am currently considering some [textual UML diagramming tools](http://modeling-languages.com/uml-tools/#textual) but I would like to know your opinions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer : I'm the EMF Compare project lead*

In the Eclipse world the [EMF Compare](http://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/) project solves that issue by providing logical diff, merge and conflict detection for any kind of model (it has a [specialization](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF_Compare/User_Guide#Compare_two_differing_branches) for UML models and diagrams).

It works with XMI files (but is not limited to) and integrates with Eclipse team support (CVS, SVN, and more especially GIT) making sure the model is always consistent even when it is split among several files.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like a good option.

Answer (score 0):

**On the rights of delirium**

Based on axiom

> XML Metadata Interchange (XMI) is an OMG standard for describing the structure for storing UML model in XML format.

If you will be able to find any tool, which can export/import XMIs (as [Visual Paradigm for UML](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/provides/interop.jsp) do), you can

- Work with UML
- Store, version, process XMI-files on the level of SCM

Comment: Somewhat correct. But
1) solving merge conflicts in large (and they get really large) is a pain and
2) most/sophisticated tools use multiple files for diagrams (which might or might not use XMI and/or DI)

Answer (score 0):

OMG defined a format for UML diagram (http://www.omg.org/spec/UMLDI/) but I guess it is not implemented by a lot of tools...
Actually each UML tools have its internal diagram representation so the solution at your problem will strongly depend of the technology used. 
If both model and diagram are formalized in XML (XMI) format, like for Eclipse-EMF based tool [Topcased](http://www.topcased.org/) or Together, I guess you can use GIT directly on the file or a more advanced tool like EMF Compare.
If you used another kind of tools, like RSx or [Modelio](http://www.modelio.org/), they have their own Control Version Service.